# Using DateTime as a variable in C#

Tags: c#

Totally new to C# so I apologize if what I'm asking isn't actually possible or doesn't make sense.

I'm currently trying to create an object called *SomeData* which stores two pieces of data, an integer and a DateTime:

```
  public class SomeData 
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public SomeData(int value1, DateTime date1)
        {
            Date = date1;
            Value = value1;
        }
    }
```

Next, I want to declare an instance of the object called *example1*, but I'm not sure how to pass a DateTime in. My code looks something like this:

```
     public List<SomeData> LoadDrillDown ()
     {    
        SomeData example1 = new SomeData (100, (2015, 6, 1));

        List<SomeData> list = new List<SomeData>();
        list.Add(example1);
        return list;
      }
```

The IDE tells me that I cannot pass in 4 arguments, so I'm rather confused.

Comment: Look up the `DateTime` constructors on MSDN.

Comment: new SomeData (100, new DateTime(2015, 6, 1));

Comment: if you are just adding date in the `DateTime` field 

     var list = new List<SomeData>{
                    new SomeData(100, new DateTime(2015,6,1))
                };enter code here

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to your constructor is a DateTime, so you need to pass in a DateTime.

```
new SomeData (100, new DateTime(2015, 6, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `DateTime` literal or initializer syntax in C#. You have to explicitly create the object using one of the constructors.

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeData example1 = new SomeData (100, (2015, 6, 1));
```

should be

```
SomeData example1 = new SomeData (100, new DateTime(2015, 6, 1));
```